# MatrixForm a product of matrices

Tags: matrix, output-formatting

I was hoping that

```
MatrixForm[SingularValueDecomposition[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}] ]
```

would neatly display the singular value decomposition of a matrix in the form of a product of three matrices, but it doesn't. I hoped for something looking like the output of

```
MatrixForm[ RandomInteger[2, {2, 2}]] * 
MatrixForm[ RandomInteger[2, {2, 2}]] * 
MatrixForm[ RandomInteger[2, {2, 2}]]
```

Is there an easy way?

Comment: Try `MatrixForm /@ SingularValueDecomposition[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]`.

Comment: That will do me, thankyou. So what I tried searching for was “spread operator” but I see that searching for "map" or "apply" was what I needed.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll I am voting to close this question because it is about a minor mistake and probably won't help other users. Please don't take that personally; it is just our clean-up policy. Nonetheless, your contributions are very welcome here.

Comment: Fine by me. I'd classify it rather as a beginner's question, not a mistake.